# R, accessing a column vector of a matrix by name

Tags: r, matrix, attributes

In R I can access the data in a column vector of a column matrix by the following:

```
mat2[,1]
```

Each column of `mat2` has a name. How can I retrieve the data from the first column by using the name attribute instead of `[,1]`?

For example suppose my first column had the name "saturn". I want something like

`mat2[,1] == mat2[saturn]`

Comment: Read the documentation, e.g. `?"["`, or any introduction to R.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
mat2[,'saturn']
```

For example:

```
> x <- matrix(1:21, nrow=7, ncol=3)
> colnames(x) <- paste('name', 1:3)
> x[,'name 1']
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm a beginner in R. also just to add that column name is case-sensitive.

Comment: Just to add it can also be done like mat2$saturn

Comment: @SaqibMustafaAbbasi in R, matrices are atomic, not recursive objects. If you try to use `$` on a matrix, you should get this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299684/r-error-in-xed-operator-is-invalid-for-atomic-vectors#23299802

Answer (score 14):

Bonus information (adding to the first answer)

```
x[,c('name 1','name 2')]
```

would return two columns just as if you had done

```
x[,1:2]
```

And finally, the same operations can be used to subset rows

```
x[1:2,]
```

And if rows were named...

```
x[c('row 1','row 2'),]
```

Note the position of the comma within the brackets and with respect to the indices.