# R Error in x$ed : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r

Here is my code:

```
x<-c(1,2)
x
names(x)<- c("bob","ed")
x$ed
```

Why do I get the following error?

> Error in x$ed : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Answer (score 121):

From the help file about `$` (See `?"$"`) you can read:

> $ is only valid for recursive objects, and is only discussed in the section below on recursive objects.

Now, let's check whether `x` is recursive

```
> is.recursive(x)
[1] FALSE
```

A recursive object has a list-like structure. A vector is not recursive, it is an atomic object instead, let's check

```
> is.atomic(x)
[1] TRUE
```

Therefore you get an error when applying `$` to a vector (non-recursive object), use `[` instead:

```
> x["ed"]
ed 
 2
```

You can also use `getElement`

```
> getElement(x, "ed")
[1] 2
```

Comment: I have come across the same error of 
`Error in object$y : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`
I have tried working thru your answer/suggestion and have not solved my problem. Maybe I don't understand your initial response. Could you please try to rephrase your answer using different a more complete example? Appreciate it

Comment: @oaxacamatt my answer is related to data.frames or lists which are recursive objects, you are using vector and that's why my answer doesn't help you. You are wrong and my answer is correct, then your downvote is invalid.

Answer (score 46):

The reason you are getting this error is that you have a `vector`.

If you want to use the `$` operator, you simply need to convert it to a `data.frame`. But since you only have one row in this particular case, you would also need to transpose it; otherwise `bob` and `ed` will become your row names instead of your column names which is what I think you want.

```
x <- c(1, 2)
x
names(x) <- c("bob", "ed")
x <- as.data.frame(t(x))
x$ed
[1] 2
```

Comment: It would be easier to use `x <- as.list(x)`.

Comment: yes  for 1 item as.list would be better.  I never use lists so I always forget about them.

Answer (score 13):

Because `$` does not work on atomic vectors. Use `[` or `[[` instead. From the help file for `$`:

> The default methods work somewhat differently for atomic vectors, matrices/arrays and for recursive (list-like, see is.recursive) objects. $ is only valid for recursive objects, and is only discussed in the section below on recursive objects.

`x[["ed"]]` will work.

Answer (score 5):

Here x is a vector.
You need to convert it into a dataframe for using $ operator.

```
 x <- as.data.frame(x)
```

will work for you.

```
x<-c(1,2)
names(x)<- c("bob","ed")
x <- as.data.frame(x)
```

***will give you output of x as:***

**bob 1

ed  2**


***And, will give you output of x$ed as:***
**NULL** 
If you want bob and ed as column names then you need to transpose the dataframe like `x <- as.data.frame(t(x))`
So your code becomes

```
x<-c(1,2)
x
names(x)<- c("bob","ed")
x$ed
x <- as.data.frame(t(x))
```

***Now the output of x$ed is:***
**[1] 2**

Answer (score 0):

You get this error, despite everything being in line, because of a conflict caused by one of the packages that are currently loaded in your R environment.

So, to solve this issue, detach all the packages that are not needed from the R environment. For example, when I had the same issue, I did the following:

```
detach(package:neuralnet)
```

bottom line: detach all the libraries no longer needed for execution... and the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me
`data<- transform(data, ColonName =as.integer(ColonName))`

Answer (score -3):

Atomic collections are accessible by `$`

Recursive collections are not. Rather the `[[ ]]` is used

```
 Browse[1]> is.atomic(list())
 [1] FALSE

 Browse[1]> is.atomic(data.frame())
 [1] FALSE

 Browse[1]> is.atomic(class(list(foo="bar")))
 [1] TRUE

 Browse[1]> is.atomic(c(" lang "))
 [1] TRUE
```

R can be funny sometimes

```
 a = list(1,2,3)
 b = data.frame(a)
 d = rbind("?",c(b))
 e = exp(1)
 f = list(d)
 print(data.frame(c(list(f,e))))

   X1 X2 X3 X2.71828182845905
 1  ?  ?  ?          2.718282
 2  1  2  3          2.718282
```

Comment: I think you have this backwards.  LIsts are recursive objects and can be accessed via $, numeric vectors are atomic and can't.  I'm not sure what you're trying to show here.