# How to get vector's TRUE names

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector:

```
table(FilterGenes)

FilterGenes

FALSE  TRUE 
 74     5
```

I'd like to see only TRUE names.

Comment: It is better to provide some example data as I am not sure what `datExpr` is.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @akrun my datExpr looks like:
row.names   Ens001            Ens002 
X1                  24.88857        28.11896 
X2                  25.03625         27.96043

Comment: If you copy/paste the output in your R console, there will be error.

Comment: What I should do/change..?

Comment: I am not sure why you get a broken dput output For example. `ENSSSCG00000000062 = c(25.38918674, 25.1447644, 25.16140268, )` after the `,`, there is no element, also, the other columns have 6 elements

Comment: Can you try `names(datExpr)[col(datExpr)][FilterGenes]`.  In the new dput, you have 6 columns with 6 column names.  and I assume `FilterGenes` for this data would be of length `prod(dim(datExpr))` and want to extract the colnames for each TRUE value in the FilterGenes

Comment: > prod(dim(datExpr))
[1] 50940

Comment: It would be, if you can post the  `FilterGenes` for this example data and the expected result, it would be great.

Comment: I think I am completely lost about what you wanted.  Your `datExp` original data is of dimension 30x1400 and the `FilterGenes` is 79.  What is the expected output?

Comment: as you see, it's a vector:
> table(FilterGenes)
FilterGenes
FALSE  TRUE 
   74     5

Comment: I understand that it is a vector, but what is your expected output?  The reason why we ask for a reproducible example is to understand what you want.  At present, I am completely clueless

Comment: datExpr contains names, as: "ENSSSCG00000000006" .....
>dimnames(data.frame(datExpr))[[2]][FilterGenes]
shows me all 79 names, extracted from datExpr,
but I want to get only the names which are TRUE..

Comment: The solution I posted in the comment extract the names that are TRUE.

Comment: You mean by this...?
>FilterGenes <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 36, replace=TRUE)

do not Works..

Comment: That was just an example to find what your expected output is.  It seems that we are both going in different directions.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to showing `true` values from the **vector** you could simply do:

```
ran.vec <- rep(c(F,T,F), 10)
ran.vec[ran.vec==TRUE]
```

I reckon that you want to filter your data frame by column having the `true` value. This could look like that:

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$someTF <- mtcars$am == 1
mtcars[mtcars$someTF == TRUE,]
```

Comment: Thank you @Konrad and I'm sorry, but I didn't get how to replace your example..

I was trying:
>FilterGenes$someTF <- FilterGenes$am == 1
Error in FilterGenes$am : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors...

Would be also nice if you could be more precise in this as well:
>ran.vec <- rep(c(F,T,F), 10)
>ran.vec[ran.vec==TRUE]

Comment: @ruta if you could post a data extract, I trust, that this could be easily solved. I'm guessing that the structure of your vector is source of the problem, have a look at [the following discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299684/r-error-in-xed-operator-is-invalid-for-atomic-vectors), it should help.