# Error in two almost identical R functions- one gets executed but not the other

Tags: r, list, function

I have written 2 R functions, both almost identical.

```
extract_verb<-function(list1){
    sd<-names(list1)
    ds<-which(sd %in% "VP")
    if(length(ds)==0){
        return(NULL)
    }
    else{
        js<-c()
        for(i in 1:length(ds)){
        js<-c(js,list1[ds[i]]$VP$VB,list1[ds[i]]$VP$VBD,list1[ds[i]]$VP$VBG,
        list1[ds[i]]$VP$VBN,list1[ds[i]]$VP$VBP,list1[ds[i]]$VP$VBZ)
        }
    return(js)
    }
}
```

and

```
extract_subject<-function(list1){
    sd<-names(list1)
    ds<-which(sd %in% "NP")
    if(length(ds)==0){
        return(NULL)}
    else{
        js<-c() 
        for(i in 1:length(ds)){
            js<-c(js,list1[ds[i]]$NP$NN,list1[ds[i]]$NP$NNP,list1[ds[i]]$NP$NNPS,
            list1[ds[i]]$NP$NNS)
        }
        return(js)
    }
}
```

I am applying these functions to some nested lists. When I apply these functions to the same list, the `extract_verb` function works just fine- but the `extract_subject` function gives an error as follows:

```
Error in list1[ds[i]]$NP$NN : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

What might be the reason? The nested list `s5` to which I am applying the functions is:

```
s5.

$NP
[1] ""

$NP
$NP$JJ
[1] "Invoice"

$NP$NN
[1] "number"


$CC
[1] "and"

[[4]]
[[4]]$NP
[1] NA

[[4]]$NP
[[4]]$NP$DT
[1] "the"

[[4]]$NP$NN
[1] "number"


[[4]][[3]]
[[4]][[3]]$VP
[[4]][[3]]$VP$VBN
[1] "mentioned"


[[4]][[3]][[2]]
[[4]][[3]][[2]]$PP
[[4]][[3]][[2]]$PP$IN
[1] "in"


[[4]][[3]][[2]][[2]]
[[4]][[3]][[2]][[2]]$NP
[1] ""

[[4]][[3]][[2]][[2]]$NP
[[4]][[3]][[2]][[2]]$NP$DT
[1] "the"

[[4]][[3]][[2]][[2]]$NP$NN
[1] "Bill"


[[4]][[3]][[2]][[2]][[3]]
[[4]][[3]][[2]][[2]][[3]]$PP
[[4]][[3]][[2]][[2]][[3]]$PP$IN
[1] "of"


[[4]][[3]][[2]][[2]][[3]][[2]]
[[4]][[3]][[2]][[2]][[3]][[2]]$NP
[[4]][[3]][[2]][[2]][[3]][[2]]$NP$NNP
[1] "Lading"
```

`extract_verb` returned `NULL` as expected

```
extract_verb(s5)
NULL
```

but `extract_subject` gives an error.

```
extract_subject(s5)
Error in list1[ds[i]]$NP$NN : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

dput output for s5 is as follows.

```
dput(s5)
structure(list(NP = "", NP = structure(list(JJ = "Invoice", NN = "number"), .Names = c("JJ", 
"NN")), CC = "and", structure(list(NP = NA_real_, NP = structure(list(
    DT = "the", NN = "number"), .Names = c("DT", "NN")), structure(list(
    VP = structure(list(VBN = "mentioned"), .Names = "VBN"), 
    structure(list(PP = structure(list(IN = "in"), .Names = "IN"), 
        structure(list(NP = "", NP = structure(list(DT = "the", 
            NN = "Bill"), .Names = c("DT", "NN")), structure(list(
            PP = structure(list(IN = "of"), .Names = "IN"), structure(list(
                NP = structure(list(NNP = "Lading"), .Names = "NNP")), .Names = "NP")), .Names = c("PP", 
        ""))), .Names = c("NP", "NP", ""))), .Names = c("PP", 
    ""))), .Names = c("VP", ""))), .Names = c("NP", "NP", ""))), .Names = c("NP", 
"NP", "CC", ""))
```

Comment: It is possble that `NP` is a `matrix` so you can use `NP[,'NN']`

Comment: No, NP is not a matrix. It is just a name for list.

Comment: Ok, my guess was based on the error showed.  If you are not providing a reproducible example, we can only guess

Comment: Have added the example now.

Comment: Can you post the dput output (`dput(s5)`) of that small example as it is difficult to test

Comment: Have added the dput output as required.

Comment: Check out the answer on [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299684/r-error-in-xed-operator-is-invalid-for-atomic-vectors). The third answer is theone that helped me

Comment: @Heuer I have seen it earlier. Question is, why only 1 function gets executed and not the other when both use the $ syntax and on the same data? I am unable to see any difference between the two as to the general structure, hence my question.

Comment: Can you add some sample data so I can reproduce the problem?

Comment: I think the error is because one of the elements dont' have NP.  You may need to have to an `if/else` condition to sort this out..  Perhaps `lapply(seq_along(ds), function(i) if(is.null(names(s5[i]$NP))) NA else s5[i]$NP$NN)`

Comment: @Heuer I have added the dput output in the question details, you can use that.

Comment: Check the first element i.e. `$NP
[1] ""` it is not a nested list.

Comment: Thanks guys. Have got some useful feedback. Will modify the thing accordingly.