# How can i add two different markers in the same Rshiny plot

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to include two different kinds of markers in the same Rshiny plot. The first marker (addCircleMarkers) works perfectly fine but when i include the second marker (addMarkers) i am getting the error message

My dataframe:

```
  Type Location.ID             Location_discription      Lat      Long Flood.path       FP_Icon Sample Structure.2
1 GBS_S         ALB                       Albany, OR 44.62054 -123.1039        Yes greenleafIcon     A1        Blue
2 GBS_S         ALB                       Albany, OR 44.62054 -123.1039        Yes greenleafIcon     A3        Blue
3 GBS_S         ALB                       Albany, OR 44.62054 -123.1039        Yes greenleafIcon     A4        Blue
4 GBS_S         ALB                       Albany, OR 44.62054 -123.1039        Yes greenleafIcon     A5        Blue
5 GBS_S         ANG Angels' rest, Columbia Gorge, OR 45.56383 -122.1523        Yes greenleafIcon   ANG1        Blue
6 GBS_S         ANG Angels' rest, Columbia Gorge, OR 45.56383 -122.1523        Yes greenleafIcon  ANG1b        Blue
  Structure.3
1       Green
2       Green
3       Green
4       Green
5       Green
6       Green
```

My ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Aspen GBS Population Structure results on map"),

  # Side bar layout
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("structure", label = "Select K for display", choices = c("2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), selected = "2"),
      radioButtons("origin", label = "Nature of the sample", choices = c("Flood", "Non Flood"), selected = "Flood")),

  mainPanel(
    leafletOutput("map")
  )
  )
)
)
```

My server.R

```
greenleafIcon <- makeIcon(
  iconUrl = "http://leafletjs.com/docs/images/leaf-green.png",
  iconWidth = 20, iconHeight = 50,
  iconAnchorX = 12, iconAnchorY = 84,
  shadowUrl = "http://leafletjs.com/docs/images/leaf-shadow.png",
  shadowWidth = 40, shadowHeight = 54,
  shadowAnchorX = 3, shadowAnchorY = 52
)

redleafIcon <- makeIcon(
  iconUrl = "http://leafletjs.com/docs/images/leaf-red.png",
  iconWidth = 20, iconHeight = 50,
  iconAnchorX = 12, iconAnchorY = 84,
  shadowUrl = "http://leafletjs.com/docs/images/leaf-shadow.png",
  shadowWidth = 40, shadowHeight = 54,
  shadowAnchorX = 3, shadowAnchorY = 52
)

library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    dt <- reactive(
        switch(input$structure,
              "2" = data_K2$Structure.2,
              "3" = data_K2$Structure.3))

    dt2 <- reactive(
      switch (input$origin,
        "Flood" = data_K2$FP_Icon,
        "Non Flood" = data_K2$FP_Icon))

    output$map <- renderLeaflet(
      leaflet(data = data_K2) %>% addTiles() %>% setView(lng = -106.1039361,lat = 50.543981, zoom = 4) %>% 
      addCircleMarkers(lat = ~Lat, lng = ~Long, popup = ~Location_discription, radius=2, color = ~dt(), fill = TRUE) %>%
      addMarkers(lat = ~Lat, lng = ~Long, popup = ~Location_discription, icon = ~dt2())
    )
})
```

The error message i am getting is - `Error in icon$iconUrl : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Where am i doing wrong here?

Comment: what I don't understand is why do you have greenleafIcon and redleafIcon if you don't use anywhere else

Comment: I used them in one of the columns in the dataframe. See the column - `FP_Icon` in my dataframe.

Comment: this thread could help you fix your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299684/r-error-in-xed-operator-is-invalid-for-atomic-vectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that is the issue is here:

`addMarkers(lat = ~Lat, lng = ~Long, popup = ~Location_discription, icon = ~dt2())`

Specifically the `~dt2()`. This evaluates to `data_K2$FP_Icon`, which is an atomic vector. Vectors cannot be subsetted with `$`.  The icon argument of `addMarkers` expects an object with subset `iconUrl`, hence the error.

What I think you want is:

```
leafIcons <- icons(
  iconUrl = ifelse(data_K2$FP_Icon == "greenleafIcon",
    "http://leafletjs.com/docs/images/leaf-green.png",
    "http://leafletjs.com/docs/images/leaf-red.png"
  ),
  iconWidth = 38, iconHeight = 95,
  iconAnchorX = 22, iconAnchorY = 94,
  shadowUrl = "http://leafletjs.com/docs/images/leaf-shadow.png",
  shadowWidth = 50, shadowHeight = 64,
  shadowAnchorX = 4, shadowAnchorY = 62
)
```

and then

`addMarkers(lat = ~Lat, lng = ~Long, popup = ~Location_discription, icon = leafIcons`

There is very helpful and clear documentation on this here: https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/markers.html

Comment: Great. It worked. I have one question though. Right now the `addMarkers` works irrespective of the second input `origin`. How can i make this `origin` integrated with  `addMarkers`?

Comment: @upendra its not clear to me from your code what it is supposed to do. Right now, it has no effect because the two outputs of the switch function are the same

Comment: I have modified my question as well as the code. Please let me know if it is still not clear. All is want is to activate the second marker (addmarker) when i use the `checkboxInput`

Comment: @upendra I would suggest rolling back your edit, as the soluition to your issue may hep other people. If you open a new question and link it here, I can answer it there

Comment: At a high level what you want to do is replace the test in `iconUrl = ifelse(data_K2$FP_Icon == "greenleafIcon",` with a user form input, and I think leafIcons will need to be reactive

Comment: yes i roll back my question. Here is the link for the second question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33685143/how-to-can-i-add-two-different-markers-with-two-different-inputs-in-r-shiny