# , "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

Tags: r

I'm trying this script in r but it gives me this error:

> Error in campione$casi: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors>

what can I do ?
I don't understand why the max function is not working properly ...

```
set.seed(316202)
dati = read.table("infezioni.dta",header = TRUE)

n = sample(c(20,25,30,35))
         
         
campione = sample(1:length(dati), n , replace = TRUE) 


k = sample(c(4,5,6))

complementare= dati[-campione, ]

x = max(campione$casi)
```

Comment: ``campione`` is a vector and so you can't use ``$`` to index it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R Error in x$ed : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299684/r-error-in-xed-operator-is-invalid-for-atomic-vectors)

Comment: ok so how do i get the maximum value?
I have seen the old questions that were asked but they don't help me

Comment: Without any data, it's hard to know what you're working with and what about this code isn't working. It seems like you've defined `campione` as a vector of numbers—maybe that wasn't your intention, which is why it's good to check what each line of your code is actually doing first