# Atomic value regarding sequence function reinforcement learning

Tags: r

Brief description:

I got a matrix based on action and states (1:25, nrow 5) and i want to be able to select the upcoming row (so whenever i am sitting on the first row no matter position i want to have an output of all the positions in the next row, example input function number 8, output = 4 9 14 19 24). Came up with a logical function but whenever i run it i get an error in environment_mat$cellnumb, $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors....

Can you maybe help a lad out here?

```
states <- seq(1,5, by = 1) 
actions <- seq(1,5, by = 1)
state_sequence <- cbind(merge(states,states), state = seq(1, length(states)*length(actions)))
environment_mat <- matrix(state_sequence$state, nrow = length(states), ncol= length(actions))
rewards_mat <- matrix(data = c(-100,10,50,16,32,40,-100,80,41,7,50,1,-100,
                               85,2,16,98,4,-100,8,32,45,95,78,-100), nrow = 5) 
environment_mat

nextCells <- function(curCell) {
  nexSta <- seq(0, max(states)-1, by = 1)*max(states)+
    environment[environment_mat$cellnum == curCell,]$y
  return(nexSta)
}
nextCells(24)
```

As explained above i tried multiple things but i cannot come up with another logical function than this

Comment: Try replacing `environment[environment_mat$cellnum == curCell,]$y` with `environment[environment_mat[["cellnum"]] == curCell,][["y"]]`. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299684/r-error-in-xed-operator-is-invalid-for-atomic-vectors) for more about this error.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for the modulo operator `%%`.

```
nextCells <- function(curCell) {
  environment_mat[(which(environment_mat == curCell) - 1L) %% nrow(environment_mat) + 2L,]
}
nextCells(24)
#> [1]  5 10 15 20 25
nextCells(8)
#> [1]  4  9 14 19 24
```

Or, more simply:

```
nextCells <- function(curCell) {
  environment_mat[(curCell - 1L) %% nrow(environment_mat) + 2L,]
}
nextCells(24)
#> [1]  5 10 15 20 25
nextCells(8)
#> [1]  4  9 14 19 24
```