# Make a boxplot interactive using Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, boxplot

I've been trying to develop an interactive boxplot with selective input in Shiny.

current code:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Sample 1"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("p", "Choose your salaries", choices = c("low"='a',"mid"='b',"high"='c',"riches!"='d'), selected = 4)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("boxplot")
    )
  )


))



library(shiny)
read.csv("Salaries.csv")

Categories <- cut (Salaries$TotalPay, breaks = c(0,36466,73678,104359,567595), labels = c("low","mid","high","riches!"))

shinyServer(function(input, output){

  output$boxplot <- renderPlot({

    if(input$p=='a'){
      i<"1"

    }

    if(input$p=='b'){
      i<-"2"
    }

    if(input$p=='c'){
      i<-"3"
    }

    if(input$p=='d'){
      i<- "riches!"
    }


    boxplot(TotalPay~Categories[i])

  })
})
```

I can't get the boxplot to react to the selection made in the UI. I suspect it has to do with the levels as when I call:

```
> Categories["riches!"]
[1] <NA>
Levels: low mid high riches!
```

'
Do i need to add factors to these? Or am I missing the point entirely?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you assigning your csv file to a dataframe? Seems to me you are missing: 
Salaries <- read.csv("Salaries.csv")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look how to [access the column by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297746/r-accessing-a-column-vector-of-a-matrix-by-name). Example below is with `mtcars` dataset

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("p","p",choices = names(mtcars)),
  plotOutput("myplot"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    boxplot(mtcars[,input$p])
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks Pork, I'll try it out and get back to you

Comment: Hey Pork,

Tried it and it gave me: error $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors..
`
    library(shiny)
    read.csv("Salaries.csv")

    Categories <- cut (Salaries$TotalPay, breaks = 
    c(0,36466,73678,104359,567595), labels = 
    c("low","mid","high","riches!"))

    shinyServer(function(input, output){
  
      output$boxplot <- renderPlot({
    
  
        boxplot(TotalPay[,Categories$p])
    
      })
   })
`

Comment: U getting errors because u have no column called `"Categories$p"`, your subset needs to be something like `"low"` or `"mid"` as you have those column names!

Comment: Quick question, the Dataset has the following columnames:

'> names(Salaries)
 [1] "Id"               "EmployeeName"     "JobTitle"         "BasePay"          "OvertimePay"     
 [6] "OtherPay"         "Benefits"         "TotalPay"         "TotalPayBenefits" "Year"            
[11] "Notes"            "Agency"           "Status"  '

Should I then use Categories is a devision of TotalPay as you probably already noticed, but TotalPay is a column in Salaries. How do I get the Categories out of TotalPay then? As low and high (i think) aren't colums either. Do I setup a new dataframe?

Comment: want me to post it here? its pretty large if anything its from here: https://www.kaggle.com/kaggle/sf-salaries

Comment: Pork, I've made it work the way I wanted it (for now) thanks a lot :).